# tracking links from another website

Tags: php, tracking

I'm looking for some resources on how to track the clicks of the links on different sites.
E.g. I'd like to know how many clicks were made on google.com for the specific image/text link? I'd like to implement it for php framework.
Thanks

Comment: You wanna know how many people clicked on a **random** image on google?

Comment: Not any image but the link that the image is linked to. I wanna track links not the images...

Comment: I mean, is the image your own or not.

Comment: oh yeah, I have access to the site with the links that need to be tracked. I'm trying to create wp plugin that will track links from my site and display reports in somebody elses site through this plugin.

Comment: Then use Analytics, as @MathieuImbert suggested. You will be able to see from where and how people opened your site. And please, rewrite the question.

Comment: unfortunately, WordPress has the policy that I can't use iframes or external load of JS for the plugins...

Comment: Well... move your site to your own independent server then :)

Comment: I have that done. By creating wp plugin I would increase the website exposure. :)

Comment: Then remove the limitations from the plugin or something like that. I don't see how you cannot use iFrames or outside JS files.

Comment: the point is that the "wordpress employee" won't let me to publish the plugin on wordpress.org if I'm using iframe/load of external JS.
Of course from technical point of view all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], insert it to a database which will contain   url | count
In the next time that somebody will go on that link from the same address, you will see that the url exists on the db and you will increase the count row.

Good luck.

Comment: This is not going to work because the OP wants to track *specific image/text links*, not only the referer.

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel?

[Google Analytics Campaign Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCampaigns) does exactly that.

Comment: this is nice but I need to implement it for wp plugin and that's not going to be very useful.

Comment: @user1684652 That is exactly why it is important to provide all the necessary information in your question.